# Shuffle list with empty (or None) elements

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, shuffle

I've got some list of lists and it values can be empty [] or NoneType

```
lst = [[[]], [1, None], 2, [[], 3], 4]
```

And I need to randomise them. To get `[[1, None], 4, 2, [[], 3], [[]]]`, for example.

But if I use shuffle(lst) I've got an exception:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

UPD: 
My mistake was that I try to put the result into variable

```
newLst = shuffle(lst)
```

That's give NoneType object.

Comment: Can't reproduce with `random.shuffle`: http://codepad.org/96uO6FJC. Perhaps show us `shuffle` function?

Comment: Also note that `random.shuffle` changes the list in-place, so it returns nothing (`None`). If you want to iterate through the resulting list, just do `for x in lst` instead of `for x in shuffle(lst)`

Comment: Ok, thanks and sorry =) My mistake was that I try to put the result into variable - that was NoneType object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the comments:**

The problem is in misunderstanding of how [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) works. You've tried to iterate through the returned value which is `None`, because `shuffle` returns nothing and changes its argument in-place.

Here's how you can solve this problem:

```
lst = [[[]], [1, None], 2, [[], 3], 4]
shuffle(lst) # Don't capture the return value
# lst is now shuffled and you can put it into `for` loop:
for x in lst:
    # something
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you shuffle in place before print or assignment.

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> lst = [[[]], [1, None], 2, [[], 3], 4]
>>> shuffle(lst)
>>> print(lst)
[2, 4, [[], 3], [1, None], [[]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the answer (that `random.shuffle` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`) - however, if you wanted to leave the list unmodified and get a "shuffled" result, then:

```
import random
shuffled = sorted(lst, key=lambda L: random.random())
```

Will do that for you.

Comment: But shuffling can be done in O(N), sorting will make it O(N lg N).

Comment: @thefourtheye true... but still cheaper than duplicating a list, shuffling then returning... it's all tradeoffs :)